# Dilema com replace em Python

Tags: python

Estou desenvolvendo um jogo da forca em Python, e para realizar a ocultação da palavra uso este pequeno código:

```
if u1 in e: # Se u1 (Variável que armazena a letra do usuário)
    for c in str(e.strip()):  # Para cada letra na palavra fatiada
        if c.lower() not in lista:  # Se a letra não estiver na lista de letras que o usuário digitou até agora
            d = d.replace(str(c), ' _')  # Troque ela por ' _'
            # Assim o objetivo seria que só as letras que o user acertou ficassem a mostra
```

Porém, esse código só funciona na primeira entrada de letra do usuário, pois na segunda entrada ele já é inutilizável devido todas as letras da váriavel que armazena a palavra agora estarem com ' _' no lugar.
Alguém sabe o que posso fazer?

Comment: Preserve a palavra original.

Comment: Muito obrigado, realizei isso e deu certo